# For loop for logistic regresion

Tags: r

Can somebody help me with my code?

I just want to get the result of this code on 100 different train and test sets.

```
library(ISLR)
library(caTools)
result=c()
for (i in 1:100){
train = sample.split(Baseballcorinf$pos, SplitRatio = 0.7)
test=Baseballcorinf[,2:10][!train,]
pos.test=Baseballcorinf$pos[!train]
glm.fit=glm(pos~year+games+at.bats+doubles+hr+hits+rbi+avg+obp,
            data=Baseballcorinf,family=binomial, subset=train)
glm.probs=predict(glm.fit,test, type="response")
glm.pred=rep("cor",length(pos.test))
glm.pred[glm.probs>.5]="inf"
tab=table(glm.pred,pos.test)
z=(tab[1,1]+tab[2,2])/90
result[i]=z}
```

`z` is one number and I  want to store it in a vector.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `Error .....  object 'Baseballcorinf' not found`

Comment: Hello Tadeas, can you please specify your error? We cannot run the code without data, and as such cannot reproduce the error you might be seeing.

Comment: At the beginning set `result = double(100)`. If it is saying that `Baseballcorin` is not found then I'm guessing that you haven't written the data in correctly. Maybe you had a typo earlier on.